# JPA HBM2DDL creating invalid foreign key constraints

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm having an issue with JPA and Hibernate. I have 2 classes (actually more but those are the 2 that are giving me a headache). 
They have a OneToMany/ManyToOne relationship, and I have specified on the OneToMany that I want it to cascade every possible change (CascadeType.ALL).

However, when I let HBM2DDL run in "update" mode, it is creating foreign key constraints that are not fitting what I want to achieve. It is creating a constraint in RESTRICT mode, which is absolutely not what I have specified. Perhaps the error is in my code ? I've joined it below.

```
@Entity
public class Department {
@Id
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private int id;
@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
private String name;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "departmentByDepartment", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Collection<Article> productsById;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "departmentByDepartment", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Collection<User> usersById;
```

And then :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product", schema = "qlog_project", catalog = "")
public class Article {
@Id
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private int id;
@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
private String name;
@Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
private String description;
@Column(name = "price", nullable = false)
private double price;
@Column(name = "image", nullable = false)
private String image;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "department", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
private Department departmentByDepartment;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "productByProductId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Collection<Stock> stocksById;
```

Also, I cannot seem to be able to delete an Article instance with EntityManager.remove(). It's not producing any query and not doing anything. Maybe it is linked ?
Thanks in advance,
Regards

Comment: Can you please show the generated DDL and the code where you try to remove an entity